# How would I remove a vertical window split in the Visual Studio 2019 IDE?

Tags: visual-studio

I have added a vertical window split in Visual Studio 2019.  The vertical window split was created using the "New Vertical Window Group" item of the Window menu.

I would like to remove the vertical window split and return to a single window.

There are no items in the menu to remove a vertical or horizontal window group.  Is there a way to remove a vertical or horizontal window group in the Visual Studio 2019 IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is (or should be) a command in the `Window` menu called "Move to Previous Document Group." This will revert to your previous arrangement.

If you set up your split view, then exit and restart the IDE, this command may be called "Move to Next Document Group" - it (seemingly) does the same thing.

Comment: I have also found that if you close all documents in a tab group, this automatically closes the tab group.

Answer (score 1):

You have to select the class you want to move to the Original Side and then select "Move to Previous Documents Group"... **one by one** or just close the classes as Doug Kimzey says.